# IIS Rewrite Input Types

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

What are the `input` types you can use in IIS rewrite rules?  The ones I mean are like as follows:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type=”Pattern” pattern="^www\.mysite\.com$" negate="true"> 
</conditions>
```

- HTTP_HOST
- URL
- REQUEST_FILENAME
- ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try the below input types.  See also [reference docs](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) for the URL Rewrite module.

- CACHE_URL
- DOCUMENT_ROOT
- HTTP_URL
- HTTP_HOST
- PATH_INFO
- PATH_TRANSLATED
- QUERY_STRING
- REQUEST_FILENAME
- REQUEST_URI
- SCRIPT_FILENAME
- SCRIPT_NAME
- SCRIPT_TRANSLATED
- UNENCODED_URL
- URL
- URL_PATH_INFO
- APP_POOL_ID
- APPL_MD_PATH
- APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH
- GATEWAY_INTERFACE
- SERVER_SOFTWARE
- SSI_EXEC_DISABLED
- SERVER_NAME

Answer (score 20):

You can also use IIS (7 and above I believe):

Open IIS => Navigate to your website => Double-click URL Rewrite => Edit a rule => Add or Edit a condition => When you start typing '{' in the 'Condition input' field, a list of types will appear.

[image: Editing an inbound rule]